# Run Script on Azure RM Server

Tags: c#, rest, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to run a powershell script on a VM that I created using Azure RM.  I've written a C# program that uses the Rest api to create the VM, now I need to run a script on the VM so it is configured properly. 
[I found this link that shows what to send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-customscript)
The problem I have is when I try to create the extension, it always ends up with the Provisioning State of Failed, and the script isn't run.

I think the problem is that the hypervisor can't download the script, however I can't get an error message from the hypervisor, and I don't know what is wrong with the JSON that I'm passing to the hypervisor.

Here's the JSON that I'm sending to create the Custom Script Extension

```
string body =
             "{                                                                                                                                 " +
            $"    \"type\" : \"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions\",                                                                  " +
            $"    \"name\" : \"{extensionName}\",                                                                                               " +
             "    \"location\" : \"eastus\",                                                                                                    " +
             "    \"tags\": {                                                                                                                   " +
            $"        \"displayName\": \"{extensionName}\"                                                                                      " +
             "      },                                                                                                                          " +
             "    \"properties\": {                                                                                                             " +
             "        \"publisher\": \"Microsoft.Azure.Extensions\",                                                                            " +
             "        \"type\": \"CustomScript\",                                                                                               " +
             "        \"typeHandlerVersion\": \"2.0\",                                                                                          " +
             "        \"autoUpgradeMinorVersion\": true,                                                                                        " +
             "        \"settings\": {                                                                                                           " +
            $"           \"fileUris\": [ \"https://{storageAccountName}.file.core.windows.net/scripts/TestScript1.ps1\",    ],                  " +             
             "        },                                                                                                                        " +
             "        \"protectedSettings\": {                                                                                                  " +
             "            \"commandToExecute\": \"PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File TestScript1.ps1\",                         " +
            $"            \"storageAccountName\": \"{storageAccountName}\",                                                                     " +
            $"            \"storageAccountKey\": \"{storageAccountAccessKey}\"  " +
             "          }                                                                                                                       " +
             "      }                                                                                                                           " +
             "}                                                                                                                                 " +
             "";
```

Here's the URL I'm doing a PUT to

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{serverName}/extensions/{extensionName}?api-version=2017-03-30
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using similar technique to install .net 4.6 and others on Service Fabric Virtual Machine Scale Set (but from the json template).

```
...
"properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
    "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.7",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": false,
    "settings": {
        "fileUris": [
            "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/DenisPitcher/d06c6cbc64765c1eb7e8c731964f2a5e/raw/6c2b87aa3e825950ad61b368490b8862f9345856/InstallNetFx46.ps1"
        ],
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File InstallNetFx46.ps1"
    },
    "forceUpdateTag": "RerunExtension"
},
"name": "CustomScriptExtensionInstallNet46"
...
```

So, what are the differences:

- I am using type CustomScriptExtension instead of your CustomScript
- I have a commandToExecute directly under settings

But in any case, you **should be** able to see the errors at https://resources.azure.com/.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, however I'm still getting the same error

Comment: What error you see when you locate your resource at https://resources.azure.com ?

Comment: You can peek at the logs on the VM as well - C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins, if you don't find anything there there also more info in C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.7\Status but that will be more about the extension than the script.